# Accessing SVN through the ssh protocol

Tags: php, svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

I have an external svn+ssh// url to all projects. How can I access them?

I'm working on windows, I know I should use TortoiseSVN. What exactly should I do to download these files from the repos?

I need quite immediate help, so I would be very glad (and feeling obligated to buy you some good polish vodka ofc :D) if you could just write me a couple of points on what should I do step-by-step?

(all tutorials I've found were describing setting the server up, not accessing it specifically...)

EDIT. And please don't blame me for asking such question, I'm doing this cause I don't wanna mess up anything and end up with all repositories deleted :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN - export through ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035431/tortoisesvn-export-through-ssh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice tutorial [here](http://www.vectorns.com/blog/technical-articles/1-tortoisesvn-over-ssh-on-windows-via-putty/).  Essentially, you set up PuTTY to connect to the target server via SSH and then TortoiseSVN utilizes that configured PuTTY session for the SSH connection.