# TortoiseSVN - export through ssh

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

I have login/password and I need to access svn through the ssh+svn// protocol.

I'm using tortoiseSVN on windows, export command to download the files.

And I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this all I do? Just export, type in the login/password, and that's it? No putty, keys, etc?
2. Why after clicking export, before typing any authentication data, I get the error, something about the lack of tunnel, can't find a specified file? Is this configuration issue, or rather I missed something?

Comment: How is this question different then [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034633/accessing-svn-through-the-ssh-protocol) you've just asked?

Comment: 2nd point in my post :P

Comment: I know I ask too many stupid questions but I have to handle this, and google doesnt really help. I hope it's not a trouble for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Securing Svnserve using SSH](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) on TortoiseSVN site or, with screenshots, [TortoiseSVN over SSH on Windows via PuTTY](http://www.vectorns.com/blog/technical-articles/1-tortoisesvn-over-ssh-on-windows-via-putty/)

Both articles for private-key auth, in case of user-pass you have only to modify settings of Putty's session